# At a minimum or a maximum why does the first approximation make no difference with small variations?

Tags: calculus, classical-mechanics

In an ordinary function like the temperature—one of the properties of the minimum is that if we go away from the minimum in the first order, the deviation of the function from its minimum value is only second order.

At any place else on the curve, if we move a small distance the value of the function changes also in the first order. But at a minimum, a tiny motion away makes, in the first approximation, no difference.

Can anyone explain geometrically , algebraically or otherwise why this is true?

For the background of where this comes from in case of any confusion the history can be easily found in the first short paragraph below figure 19-7   provided by this link http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_19.html#Ch19-SUM

( Not sure how to cut paste pictures yet, but figure 19-8 is one click away. ) The other caveat is that this question may be more appropriate for a physicist.

Comment: Please notice all the second order terms are dropped from the equation in the variations difference from the true path.  ALL calculus of variations examples using the Lagrangian do this!   The difference in kinetic and potential energy second terms are grouped together and dropped .   This can clearly be seen in examples I have found on the internet and textbooks , The mystery of why this is done is the motivation of the problem!  It's either very subtle and not noticed or I am not noticing something very simple.

Answer (score 2):

We say that a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrowtail \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at a point $a \in \text{Int}(\text{dom}(f))$ if there exists $A \in \mathbb{R}$ and $r: \text{dom}(f) \to \mathbb{R}$ function with $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{r(x)}{x-a}$ so that
$$f(x)=f(a)+A(x-a)+r(x)$$
And of course $A=f'(a)$.

So if we have that $f'(a)=0$, then
$$f(x)=f(a)+r(x)$$
So there is no first order change in $f$.

An example: $f(x):=x^2$ and $a:=0$. Then we have that
$$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)(x-0)+r(x)$$
Substituting back everything:
$$x^2=0+0*x+r(x)$$
$$r(x)=x^2$$
So as you can see, the change around $a=0$ is second order. On the other hand, if we pick a different $a$, for example $a:=1$, we get that
$$f(x)=f(1)+f'(1)(x-1)+r(x)$$
$$f(x)=1+2(x-1)+r(x)$$
So we have a first order term as well. And the higher order term will be:
$$r(x)=x^2-1-2(x-1)$$
$$r(x)=x^2-2x+1$$
$$r(x)=(x-1)^2$$
I used here that I already know $f'(a)$, but you can calculate it this way:
$$f(x)-f(a)=A(x-a)+r(x)$$
$$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=A+\frac{r(x)}{x-a}$$
And now you can let $x \to a$, use the properties of $r$, and you will get that $A$ is just $f'(a)$.

Comment: is there anyway you can provide a simple example  ...let us say the function x squared ?

Comment: @Sedumjoy Maybe something like this?

Comment: does second order mean you are getting closer to some desired value ?  and if so then why can Feynman toss away the second order terms for the potential and kinetic energy ?   the mystery I seek and the motivation for the question...you may need to refer to  my link

Comment: @Sedumjoy Could you please include the questionable line(s) in your question?

Comment: Yes of course be happy too. The culprit is on line 16 which is located just a few paragraphs below Fig. 19-9 starting with these words " I have written V'..."     By the way I am not including the equations as lines so you will need to count 16 text lines.....just a quick glance away.  I understand all the other math believe or not just can't figure what gives him the luxury of dropping all the second order terms ....I have been working on this on and off for a few weeks in between other math problems and still puzzles me

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a sufficiently smooth function, the [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) around a point $\,a\,$ can be written as:

$$
f(x) = f(a) + {\frac {f'(a)}{1!}}(x-a)+{\frac {f''(a)}{2!}}(x-a)^{2}+ \mathcal{O}\big((x-a)^3\big)
$$

If $\,a\,$ is a local extremum then $\,f'(a)=0\,$, so the lowest non-constant term is of $2^{nd}$ order or higher.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a geometric reason. The first approximation to a differentiable function at a point follows the tangent line instead of the curve as you move away from the point. At a minimum or maximum the tangent is horizontal. The first approximation is $0$ change; you have to look at the second approximation to get an idea of how the graph departs from horizontal.

Comment: yes I can see that !  so then why are  the second order variation terms  dropped from the variation of the function S in the example I provide?  That is the mystery of why I ask the question!    All calculus of variation problems do this!   they arrange any second  order terms of the kinetic and potential energy together and DROP them from the  equation ...this is a mystery to me